# How To Set WPF DataGrid TextTrimming Property Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have some WPF `DataGrid` that are styling very nicely in C# code as shown below. The `TextAlignment`, `TextWrapping`, and `ToolTip` are all working correctly. However, I can't get the ellipsis `TextTrimming` to appear. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public static void FormatGrid(ref DataGrid oDataGrid, List<ColumnFormat> oColumnFormats)
{
    oDataGrid.CanUserResizeColumns = true;
    SetHighlightBrush(ref oDataGrid, oUser);
    oDataGrid.Background = GetBackgroundBrush(oUser);
    oDataGrid.Foreground = GetBrushForeground(oUser, ColorType.Medium);

    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < oDataGrid.Columns.Count; iColumn++)
    {
        DataGridColumn oColumn = oDataGrid.Columns[iColumn];
        ColumnFormat oColumnFormat = GetColumnFormat(oColumn);
        if (oColumn.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            if (oColumnFormat != null)
            {
              oColumn.CellStyle = GetCellStyle(oColumnFormat.ColumnName);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static Style GetCellStyle(string sToolTipPath)
{
    Style oCellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
    SetterBaseCollection oSetters = GetStyleSetters(sToolTipPath);
    foreach (Setter oSetter in oSetters)
    {
        oCellStyle.Setters.Add(oSetter);
    }
    return oCellStyle;
}

private static SetterBaseCollection GetStyleSetters(string sToolTipPath)
{
    SetterBaseCollection oSetters = new SetterBaseCollection();
    Setter oTextAlignment = new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);
    oSetters.Add(oTextAlignment);
    Setter oTextWrapping = new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.NoWrap);
    oSetters.Add(oTextWrapping);
    Setter oTextTrimming = new Setter(TextBlock.TextTrimmingProperty, TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis);
    oSetters.Add(oTextTrimming);
    Setter oToolTip = new Setter(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, new Binding(sToolTipPath));
    oSetters.Add(oToolTip);
    return oSetters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you exactly what the cause of your problem is, other than it seems TextTrimming is a special case for whatever XYZ reason. Even trying to set it via XAML, this works in my custom DataGrid CellStyle:

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
```

While this does not:

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

So long story short, I had a similiar-ish problem that might be a solution for you to adapt, in terms of doing via the CodeBehind. It requires overriding the AutoGeneratingColumn event for the DataGrid and then using a custom column that sets the TextTrimming property when the element is generated. Works like a charm. Here's some quick pseudo-code that should get you started (in VB, my apologies!):

```
    Private Sub CustomDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles Me.AutoGeneratingColumn
        e.Cancel = True
        Dim binding As New Binding
        Dim textColumn = TryCast(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
        If textColumn IsNot Nothing Then
            binding = textColumn.Binding
            binding.TargetNullValue = "-"
        End If
        Columns.Add(New CustomColumn() With {.Header = e.Column.Header, .Binding = binding})
    End Sub
```

...

```
Public Class CustomColumn
Protected Overrides Function GenerateElement(cell As DataGridCell, dataItem As Object) As FrameworkElement
    Dim block As New TextBlock()
    Dim column As CustomColumn = DirectCast(cell.Column, CustomColumn)
    Dim binding As Binding = DirectCast(column.Binding, Binding)
    If binding IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim cellBinding As New Binding(binding.Path.Path)
        cellBinding.Source = dataItem
        cellBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        cellBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = True
        cellBinding.ValidatesOnExceptions = True
        cellBinding.NotifyOnValidationError = True
        cellBinding.ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors = True
        cellBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
        block.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, cellBinding)
        block.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis
    End If

    Return block
End Function
End Class
```